# Calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}$

Tags: limits

I want to find the following limits: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}$.

For the first one I use de l'Hospital rule:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{e^{2x}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{2e^{2x}}=0$$

but I don't know how to calculate the one in $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indeterminate form for $x \to -\infty$ since:
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x+1) = -\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^{-2x} = +\infty$$
so what about their product...?

Comment: Their product goes to $- \infty$. Sorry for that question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No need to apolgize; you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Let’s set y=-x

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x+1)e^{-2x} = \lim_{y \to +\infty} (1-y)e^{2y} = -\infty$$

NOTE

when you have limits to negative values often is better to change variable sign in order to work with limits to positive value

Answer (score 0):

For $x\to \infty$
$$\lim_{x \to \,\infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}=\lim_{x \to \,\infty}\frac{(x+1)}{e^{2x}}$$
With L'Hopital's Rule we have:
$$\lim _{x\to \,\infty }\left(\frac{1}{e^{2x}\cdot 2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \lim _{x\to \,\infty }\left(\frac{1}{e^{2x}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\lim _{x\to \,\infty }\left(1\right)}{\lim _{x\to \,\infty }\left(e^{2x}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\infty }=0$$

---

New for $x\to \,-\infty$
$$\lim_{x \to \,-\infty}(x+1)e^{-2x}=\underbrace{\lim _{x\to \, -\infty }\left(x+1\right)}_{l_1}\cdot\underbrace{\lim _{x\to \,-\infty }\left(e^{-2x}\right)}_{l_2} = \infty \cdot -\infty = -\infty$$
***Note:*** 
$$l_1 = \lim _{x\to \,-\infty }\left(x+1\right)=-\infty$$
$$l_2 =\lim_{x\to \,-\infty }\left(e^{-2x}\right) = \infty$$
Let $u = -2x \implies \lim _{x\to \, -\infty }\left(-2x\right) = -2\cdot -\infty = \infty \implies \lim_{u\to \,-\infty }\left(e^{u}\right) = \infty$